# Typescript mongoose - undefined object in my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I don't understand why my Promise is not fulfilled, if i understand: my objects created from my mongodb documents should fill my array and here its give an undefined so my object are empties right?

**product.resolver.ts**

```js
import { Resolver, Query, Arg, Int, ObjectType, Mutation } from 'type-graphql';
import { Product, ProductModel, ProductResponse } from './product.type';
import { filterItems, getRelatedItems } from '../../helpers/filter';
import { createProductSamples } from './product.sample';

@Resolver()
export class ProductResolver {
  private readonly items: Product[] = createProductSamples();

  @Query(() => Product)
  async product(
    @Arg('slug', (type) => String) slug: string
  ): Promise<Product | undefined> {
    return await this.items.find((item) => item.slug === slug);
  }

}
```

**product.sample.ts**

Here is the function to fetch data from mongodb and populate my array with documents objects

```js
import { Product, ProductModel }  from './product.type';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export function createProductSamples() {
  //const inventory = useQuery<InventoryData>(GetInventory);
  const data = ProductModel.find();
  console.log(data);
  return plainToClass(Product, [data]);

}
```

**product.type.ts**

here is the related class

```js
@ObjectType()
export class Product {

  @Field()
  @Property()
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Property()
  slug: string;

  @Field()
  @Property()
  title: string;

  @Field(() => ProductType)
  @Property()
  type: ProductType;

  @Field(() => [Category])
  @Property()
  categories: Category[];

  @Field()
  @Property()
  unit: string;

  @Field()
  @Property()
  image: string;

  @Field(() => [Gallery])
  @Property()
  gallery: Gallery[];

  @Field()
  @Property()
  description: string;

  @Field()
  @Property()
  price: number;

  @Field()
  @Property()
  salePrice: number;

  @Field()
  @Property()
  discountInPercent: number;

  @Field(() => Author, { nullable: true })
  @Property()
  author?: Author;

  @Field(() => Meta, { nullable: true })
  @Property()
  meta?: Meta;

  @Field()
  @Property()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

**Output GraphQl**

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "product"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined",
            "    at new NativeCollection ............................
            ...............................
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Comment: Please show the output that you have question about. Seeing it in code might give more insight than plain words explanation. Shouldn't you do `const data = await ProductModel.find()` ? And I think `data` should already be an array, there is no need to do `[data]`

Comment: When i remove the brackets i have an error here   private readonly items: Product[] = createProductSamples(); saying Type 'Product' is missing the following properties from type 'Product[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2740).

For the await i can't add it because i don't understand where to place my async in this case.

I have added the graphql output

Comment: Hey, i propgressed with your suggestion, i found where to place my async now i get this output from graphql :       "message": "this.items.find is not a function", and still get the same error on items of private readonly items: Product[] = createProductSamples(); saying the same thing as previous comment